# Problem about signed ranked test.

Tags: probability

This is the problem.

Average cardiac index of normal people is 3.50(liters/$minm^2$). Following data is from 20 people who had a cardiac disorder and want to test if the cardiac index of people who had a cardiac disorder is lower than 3.50.

2.45 3.55 4.05 0.95 1.90 3.48 3.80 1.40 3.65 3.30 2.33 2.91 3.69 1.83 1.35 4.10 2.77 2.60 3.32 2.34
Find a proper hypothesis and do the signed ranked test.(translation is poor, sorry)

My answer is $H_0$ : $\theta$ = 3.50(=$\theta_0$), $H_1$ : $\theta$ < 3.50

Also, in text book, the definition for statistics are given as

$W_n$ = $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n$sign(X$_i$ - $\theta_0$)$R(|X_i -\theta_0)|)$ 
or $W^+_n$ = $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n$I(X$_i$ - $\theta_0$>0)$R(|X_i -\theta_0)|)$ 
where $R(|X_i -\theta_0)|)$ is rank of $|X_i -\theta_0)|$.
I calculated both statistics and they are -28 and 91

But the solution in the text is different.
It says that proper hypothesis is $H_0$ : $\theta$ >= 3.50(=$\theta_0$), $H_1$ : $\theta$ < 3.50 Also, it only calculates $W^+_n$ and its value is 36. So under the significance level of 0.05, it rejects null hypothesis while my solution can not reject.

What did I do wrong? I think I don't fully understand signed rank test.

Comment: I am echoing back the data as I copied them:  x = c(2.45, 3.55, 4.05, 0.95, 1.90, 3.48, 3.80, 1.40, 3.65, 3.30, 2.33, 2.91, 3.69, 1.83, 1.35, 4.10, 2.77, 2.60, 3.32, 2.34)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some points to put you on the right track. I hope looking at them
along with your text you resolve your difficulty.

It does not matter whether $H_0$ has $=$ or $\le$. Different texts have
different conventions. (And you should clean up the typos in your question
because others may be interested in this example.)

Pasting your data into R, I get $W_n^+ = 35.$

When I do this Wilcoxon test in R with your data, I get a very small
P-value, so rejecting is not a close call.

A histogram of these data did not warn me away from a t-test, so I
did one and got a very small P-value, confirming that this really is no
'borderline' rejection.